# jQuery Datatable Sorting bug/error Chrome Specific need work around

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

Here my code

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseFloat( x );
    y = parseFloat( y );
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseFloat( x );
    y = parseFloat( y );
    return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ledger').dataTable({
        bAutoWidth: false,
        bJQueryUI : true,
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: false,
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        bStateSave : false,
        bUseRendered: false,
        iDisplayLength: ${entriesValue},
        sDom: mw.superadmin.datatable.relatedListDom,
        aLengthMenu: mw.superadmin.datatable.relatedListLengthMenu,
        aaSorting: [[0,'asc']],
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            { "iDataSort": 2},
            { "bVisible": false, "sType": "num"},
            { "iDataSort": 4, "bSortable": true },
            { "bVisible": false, "sType": "num"}
        ]
    });
```

This table works 100% through and through without issue on IE, FF, Opera, and Safari to my knowlege however with Chrome it fails misserablly but only on 1 specific column of my sortable set. I can't figure it out, and need a little assistance.

An example of what its doing on Chrome can be found in the image below.
[image]

Personally I feel its cause its got characters like ( , [ } ) etc in it.. However like I said other browsers not a problem, Chrome is the only one giving me an issue on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem where the datatable in Chrome was failing to sort on one column amongst nine. Yet it worked perfectly in Firefox.

To make it work in Chrome, I had to explicitly specify the [sType](http://www.datatables.net/ref#sType) for **all** the columns.

In my case "html" worked fine.

```
$('#xxx').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"sType": "html"},
        {"sType": "html"},
        {"sType": "html"}
     ]
});
```

I guess the auto-detection of column type is failing in Chrome somehow.

Comment: Awesome ill have to give this a shot. I am still having troubles with it. I have found through discussions with the developer and searching around that this is a Chrome specific bug coupled with the way datatables was developed. In short Chrome handles the data type ever so slightly different and in the sorting it gets lost in translation. It combines both HTML and String as a string and because html is in the string the sort is mega off pending on what html you have in said string, in my case links with hidden parameters for other things.

Comment: @chris Interesting, my problem column was pure text.

Comment: This worked for me and the column that didn't work was pure text. Oddly, other columns worked.

Comment: I love stack overflow.

Comment: Had same issue but using `mRender` to override display, found you can change `if (type === 'display') {...}` to `if (type === 'display' || type === 'type') {...}` and that makes it work also.